# how to retain partial curl in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that comprises a number of pages. Instead of leaving it to the user to discover my pagination, I want the current page to have a partial curl so the user knows there are more than one pages. I don't want to use the multiple dots of the UIPageController as indicator. Does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with the dots? Have a look at https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl.

Comment: I have tried all kinds of things. The dots aren't the design I want.

Comment: You could try to build your custom design by modifying XBPageCurl.